# Use "/" as Optional Separator for Parameters in Url - Angular-Ui-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I've a tricky issue that I was not able to solve in a while.

Essentially, when I'm on a certain `$route` and I do a certain `$state.go(routeName, params);`, I need to append a certain `parameter` or multiple `parameters` to the url.

Also, paying attention to the fact that route can also be visited with no parameters at all, so it has to be clean.

I would like to achieve this result:

- Actual Url: `localhost:4000`
- Wanted Url: `localhost:/4000/myRoute/myStuff/myParam`
- Avoid     : `localhost:/4000/myRoute//` if a `$state.go(myRoute)` with no parameters is provided.

For instance:

```
$state.go(myRoute, {
   param1 : 'myStuff',
   param2 : 'myParam'
});

function myRoute($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('myRoute', {
            url: 'myRoute/{param1}{param2}',
            parent: 'myParent'
              . . .
        })
}
```

Will work but giving `localhost:/4000/myRoute/myStuffmyParam`.

So, I tried using `/` as separator `url: 'myRoute/{param1}' + '/' + '{param2}'`
and it works just fine, I get `localhost:/4000/myRoute/myStuff/myParam`.

But, of course, `/` gets appended even if there are no parameters.
For instance, doing `$state.go('myRoute')` will lead to `localhost:/4000/myRoute//` that is clearly wrong.

Now, then, I told myself, well, maybe if I just add it to `param1` I will achieve what I need.

So, I tried with

- `param1 : 'myStuff' + '/'`
- `param1 : 'myStuff' + '\/'`
- `param1 : 'myStuff/'`
- `param1 : 'myStuff\/'`

But all lead to the same url `localhost:4000/myRoute/myStuff~2FmyParam`.
While, if I use another separator like `-` it works just fine.

`param1 : 'myStuff-'` leads to `localhost:4000/myRoute/myStuff-myParam`

**EDIT**

Using `{param}` and `:param` is the same. Reference [angular-ui/ui-router URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

I don't find any solution also looking at answers provided at [way to create optional parameter in url?](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108). Trying `myRoute[/:param1[/:param2]]` will also throw an error.

**EDIT**

Also trying `param1%2F` or `'param1' + '%2F'` won't work. 
I respectively get `~2F` & `%252f` as separator. Also doing a `decodeURI('%2F')` leads to the same miserable result.

- **Whats the proper way to use such separator, avoiding it to be appended when there are no parameters and also get rendered properly?**

For any clarification just leave a comment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to have parameter in your parent state?

Comment: @adashbob as I wrote on the question, this will lead to always have `myRoute//` even with no parameters at all. @aravind no, not in the parent, in the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make all this kind of machinery to achieve what you want. As @trichetriche said, you can create a certain set of child routes.

You need to edit your `$routeProvider` like:

```
//for the clean url - localhost:/4000/myRoute/
$stateProvider
    .state('myRoute', {
        url: 'myRoute/',
        parent: 'myParent'
          . . .
})
//for myStuff/param1 url - localhost:/4000/myStuff/param1
$stateProvider
    .state('myRoute.myStuff', {
        url: 'myStuff/{param1}', //also adding other params
        parent: 'myRoute'
          . . .
})
```

You can add as many children as you want if you need them.

With respectively  $state.go's:

- `$state.go('myRoute');`
- `$state.go('myRoute.myStuff', { param1 : 'HeyOhLetsGo' });`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Didn't really think about that. It's also definitely easier than what I wanted to do. Thanks.

Comment: This is so unfair, I wanted that bounty :'(

Answer (score 3):

```
$stateProvider.state('state', {
    url: "/state/:id/:name/:something",
    templateUrl: "bla.html",
    controller: 'BlaCtrl'
  });

$state.go('state', {id: 1, name: 'pepe', something: 'nothing'});
```

This works for me, produces: **/state/1/pepe/nothing**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It works when there are parameters, but, if I do a `$state.go(myRoute)` with no parameters is appends '/' in any case.

Comment: Well, if you want "/" that's the way to do it. If you want optional parameters, then you are stuck with named params.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create a mother route, and a child route ? Isn't this possible ?